# Codeigniter - refresing multiple elements with multiple contents using JQuery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

what I want to achieve is that multiple divs in my view get fill up with different content using ajax at the same time when a button is clicked, let's say something like this:

view:

```
<div id="one">
</div>

<div id="two">
</div>

<div id="three">
</div>
```

div one, two and three should be refreshed with different content each one.

my script is:

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var mail= $("#mail").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        $.ajax({
              url: '<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/login/theLogin',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {'mail':mail, 'password':password},
              success: function(data) {
                $('div#one').html(data);
                $('div#two').html(data);
                $('div#three').html(data);
            }
          });
      });
```

controller:

```
public function theLogin()
{

  $this->load->view("ajax/newContent");
}
```

newContent.php:

```
<div id="ajax-one">
one
</div>

<div id="ajax-two">
two
</div>

<div id="ajax-three">
three
</div>
```

and the result is obviously the three divs in my view get refreshed with three divs (9 divs in total), but I don't want that, I want that div one gets refreshed only with the content of div ajax-one and so on.

I used something like this in my ajax method but no success:

```
    success: function(data) {

                    $('#one').html($('#ajax-one' , data).html());
                    $('#two').html($('#ajax-two' , data).html());
                    $('#three').html($('#ajax-three' , data).html());

                }
```

What possible solution could exists to solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace the DIVs with the new DIVs. So if you have a parent DIV you can replace the whole thing with the new data.

Consider this being your initial view:

```
<div id="myWrapperDiv">
  <div id="one">
  </div>

  <div id="two">
  </div>

  <div id="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

When your data is returned do this:

```
$("#myWrapperDiv").html(data);
```

UPDATE:

Since that was not a good option for you I have come up with another possible solution. Personally I would return a JSON array that separated the DIVs, however, I will offer a suggestion to work with your current code. I would split the return into an array and process it from there.

Let me show you. In the below we split the data on the closing div tags with a limit of 3. Without the limit you will get an empty string at the end of your array. Then we replace the contents of your DIVs with the ajax DIVs. We have to add back the closing div tags since it was removed when we split the data. I hope this helps :).

```
var myArray = data.split("</div>",3);
$("#one").html(myArray[0] + "</div>");
$("#two").html(myArray[1] + "</div>");
$("#three").html(myArray[2] + "</div>");
```

Comment: No, I need it in that way for some other reasons, but thanks. Any idea?

Comment: @user2580401 I have updated my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: What will happen if there are nested `DIV` in ajax response?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal that would break the logic of course and is why I would use a JSON array return form the server. His example didn't have this situation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/szptfwem/1/). Change you response data to jQuery object. Hope this is what you need.

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    var data = '<div id="ajax-one"><span>one</span></div><div id="ajax-two">two</div><div id="ajax-three">three</div>';
    var $dataObj = $(data);
    $('#one').html($dataObj[0]);
    $('#two').html($dataObj[1]);
    $('#three').html($dataObj[2]);    
 });
```